# Ошибка при инициализации vector<string>

Tags: c++, компиляция

Добрый день! Я студент технического вуза и самостоятельно пытаюсь выучить c++.
Что пытаюсь сделать :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что у меня в IDE:

```
    int main()
{
    vector<string> philosopher = { "Kant", "Plato","Hume","Kierkegaard" };
    return 0;
}
```

Что показывает мне компилятор на попытку собрать решение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои #include:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdexcept>
```

Я могу просто определить вектор строк и с помощью метода push.back() добавить туда строку.
Но вот так создать вектор у меня не получается, хотя вышеуказанный пример из книги Страуструпа. Я что-то делаю не так?

Заголовочный файл - книжный. Автор книги говорит добавлять его во все программы и потом объяснить его назначение. Ссылка - [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h)

Comment: Вы точно все так написали? https://ideone.com/9UsHU2 - все компилируется. Какой у вас компилятор?

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. Почему у вас в сообщении об ошибке сказано `Vector`, а в коде - `vector`? Откуда вдруг взялся `Vector`?

Comment: Microsoft visual studio, стандарт языка c++ 14

Comment: Заметьте, что в C++ все идентификаторы чувствительны к регистру, и `Vector` и `vector` будут обозначать разные вещи.

Comment: @AnT нет, не выдумываю. Может на это влияет заголовочный файл от книги?
https://b.radikal.ru/b15/1712/1b/0a976f4d5a37.png

Comment: @VTT мои #include из другого файла, который был скачен с сайта stroustrup.com.
https://d.radikal.ru/d27/1712/0c/81af868e10e1.png

Comment: Откуда вы взяли ссылку на это файл? Книга, которую вы привели выше, ссылается на него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как оно должно выглядеть

```
// прекомпилированный заголовочный файл (в студии используется по-умолчанию)
// должен быть первым
#include "stdafx.h"

// все инклюды, требуемые этому файлу, перечисляются прямо в этом файле, а не где-то еще
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    ::std::vector< ::std::string > philosopher = {"Kant", "Plato", "Hume", "Kierkegaard"};
    // альтернативный вариант
    // чтобы нормально подхватить vector и string не указывая префикс каждый раз
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> philosopher = {"Kant", "Plato", "Hume", "Kierkegaard"};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код компилируется и работает, спасибо.
Я убрал заголовочный файл с сайта, добавив только vector и string, добавив using namespace std;

Comment: По два двоеточия перед `std` зачем ставить?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Чтобы жестко указать, что нужно пространство `std` именно из глобального пространства имен.

Comment: @VTT Из какого оно ещё может быть (не считая хулиганов).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan А это как самолет посадить вверх ногами, кажется невероятным, но на деле запросто.

Answer (score 4):

В том заголовочном файле, который вы используете, Страуструп подменяет вектор своим - он кое-чем отличается, в частности, он генерирует исключения при выходе за границы в операторе `[]`.

Так вот, в этом его классе **нет** конструктора, который умеет работать со списком инициализации.

В тексте Страуструп показывает работу со *стандартным* вектором.

Answer (score 3):

У вас наблюдается мешанина из современной книги по С++ (С++11 и позже) и старинных заголовочных файлов, не совместимых с современным С++ (написаны для С++98-С++03). Обратите внимание на комментарий в файле: "Revised April 25, 2010". В то время как вы пытаетесь использовать свойство языка, которое появилось только в 2011 году.

Ошибка возникает из-за

```
#define vector Vector
```

во включенном вам заголовочном файле. При этом интерфейс суррогатного класса `Vector` грубо не соответствует современным требованиям языка. Страуструп в свое время сильно "напортачил" с этим `std_lib_facilities.h`, что вызвало большое количество ошибок и вопросов. Старайтесь избегать учебных курсов по современному С++, опирающихся на этот `std_lib_facilities.h`.

Comment: Вот и что подумают люди о C++ когда им создатель языка собственноручно с ходу такую свинью подкладывает.

Comment: @VTT: Я что-то сомневаюсь в том, что современные книги Страуструпа ссылаются на тот `std_lib_facilities.h`. Неужели?

Comment: А такой дефайн являлся форменным безобразием еще когда содержимое `std_lib_facilities.h` было актуальным. В этом плане ничего принципиально не поменялось.

Comment: @AnT Я сейчас посмотрел, у меня перевод второго издания, датирован 2016 годом (с добавлением стандарта с++14). Я не знаю, вышло ли что-то новее, но вот эта книга ссылается на этот файл.
https://a.radikal.ru/a22/1712/a8/3df173f8502f.png

Comment: @Sergey Заливайте картинки на imgur

Comment: @VTT: Да, тут не поспоришь. Попытка "улучшить" `vector` (!) для целей обучения (!!) да еще и через `#define vector Vector` (!!!). Как Страуструп умудрился до такого додуматься - не ясно.

Comment: @VTT https://imgur.com/a/49kDm